# Java External Sorting Efficiency

Tags: java, sorting, external

I have to write an external sorting program in java which given a file A containing an arbitrary number of integers, sorts them using only file B (which is the same size) as temporary storage. For the first stage I am reading blocks of the file into ram, using the inbuilt java sort and writing back to file B, however this is proving to be very slow. I would like to know if there are any glaring inefficiencies in my code? Note that input1 and output are RandomAccessFile Objcets and BUFFER_SIZE is the block size decided at runtime by the amount of free memory.

```
public void SortBlocks() throws IOException{
    int startTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    input1.seek(0);output.seek(0);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(input1.getFD()),2048));
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output.getFD()),2048));
    int[] buffer = new int[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<input1.length();i+=4){
        buffer[j] = in.readInt();
        j++;
        if(j == BUFFER_SIZE){
            writeInts(buffer,out,j);
            j=0;
        }
    }
    writeInts(buffer,out,j);
    out.flush();
    SwitchIO();
    int endTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("sorted blocks in " + Integer.toString(endTime-startTime));
}

    private static void writeInts(int[] Ints, DataOutputStream out, int size) throws IOException{
    Arrays.sort(Ints,0,size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        out.writeInt(Ints[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: randomAccessFile has a readInt and a writeInt why are you wrapping them with a FileStream, BufferedStream and DataStream, just use readInt and writeInt

Comment: Is this homework? Because that's far from the most efficient way to sort an arbitrarily large amount of data. You should be looking at an initial run distribution followed by a balanced or polyphase merge.

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment, we have to try and sort in the least possible time. My solution works but I'm trying to optimise. What is a run distribution and polyphase merge? I'd be grateful if you could provide some links to explanations.

Comment: And to answer ratchet freak, the wrapping ensures buffered I/O which is much faster than making a system call for every readInt() operation.

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring inefficiency is the use of `input1.length()` which is a relatively expensive operation and you are calling it on every `int` value.

I can't see why you decrease the buffer size when the default (8192) would be more efficient.

If you are reading files, I would use a ByteBuffer as an IntBuffer.  A bottleneck is likely to be the way you read and write data. Using `int` values in native order would improve the translation performance. (Rather than the default which big endian)

If you access the file as a memory mapped file you may be able to gracefully handle files larger than the memory size.

Comment: Thanks for your help - calling length() only once has reduced the time by a factor of 14! I was experimenting with different buffer sizes and forgot to change back, although this doesn't seem to be where the bottleneck is. If I read bytes into a byte buffer and then use getInt to put the resulting integers into another array won't I require twice as much memory? I guess this is a worthwhile tradeoff if it is much faster.

Comment: If you memory map the file as an IntBuffer, you don't need to use any heap or direct memory. However you can't use Arrays.sort() i.e. you would have to write your own sort.

Comment: Unfortunately memory mapping is forbidden - we are only allowed to use the memory allocated to the JVM!

Comment: Yes - and they think it defeats the object to allow extra memory. I am currently using the above method to write sorted blocks and then using a heap method to combine the blocks. My program works, I'm just desperate for further optimization!

Comment: I would test you application without the sort (comment it out), as I expect you are limited by the way you read/write data.  Without a different approach to read/writing data, you need faster hardware to improve performance.

Comment: As predicted, the SortBlocks runs no faster when no sorting actually takes place! Any ideas for speeding up the I/O without using memory mapping? Increasing the buffer size doesn't seem to help. I had also thought about reading in bytes and writing a custom sort, but this could get very messy.

Comment: BTW: If its homework, you should tag it as so.  It doesn't suprise me that you are limited by the speed your system can read/wrte big-endian.  Memory Mapping not might help much actually as the native byte order for your platform (x86/x64) is likely to be little endian and I assume you can't change the endian-ness of the file. i.e. it will spend most of its time swapping the bytes around. :P

Comment: Though there are definitely optimizations to be made, as other people are enjoying slightly faster sorting speeds. Maybe I should focus on  the second stage of sorting if you think there's not much more that can be done with this method.

Comment: Perhaps you can make assumptions about the data but you won't be faster than not sorting at all.